# Empty route path for different methods in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, methods, routes, fosrestbundle

I'm developing an API using Symfony and FOSRestBundle, and want to use the following routes:

**app/config/routing.yml**

```
page:
  prefix: /page
  resource: "@PageBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

**PageBundle/Resources/Config/routing.yml**

```
page_get:
  path: /{id}
  methods: GET
  defaults:
    _controller: PageBundle:Page:get
    id: null

page_post:
  path: /
  methods: POST
  defaults:
    _controller: PageBundle:Page:post
```

The same for PUT and DELETE...

When I call GET for /page works fine, but when call POST for /page I get the following error:

```
No route found for "POST /page": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET, HEAD)
```

I need to call **/page/** instead of **/page**, then it works...

What can I do to use the same empty path for differents methods?

*Sorry for my bad english.*

Comment: did you try   methods:  ['GET','POST'] ? there are some point in yml section here http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/requirements.html#adding-http-method-requirements

Comment: The methods is working, but the route for POST /page is not found, only POST /page/.
And GET /page is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is remove `prefix` from **app/config/routing.yml**

```
page:
    resource: "@PageBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

And add it to path in **PageBundle/Resources/Config/routing.yml**

```
moodul_page_get:
    path: /page/{id}
    methods: GET
    defaults:
        _controller: MoodulPageBundle:Page:get
        id: null

moodul_page_post:
    path: /page
    methods: POST
    defaults:
        _controller: MoodulPageBundle:Page:post
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I know, but I want to keep the prefix in **app/config/routing.yml** because I have more bundles sharing the same structure of PageBunde.

Comment: You need to define for your self is `/page` **prefix** or **path**?

Comment: I have more bundles like PageBundle that will be shared  across multiple applications.
So I want to manage the routes in each application with **prefix** in routing.yml